# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/7938).**

Aviation is scheduled for an election [next week, August 19](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/3). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until August 19 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 9):

**How would you deal with an enthusiastic user that produces mostly chaff, non-answers, or outright wrong answers but occasionally does contribute a good and useful reply?**

For the sake of argument, assume the ratio is significant, e.g. 20 bad answers for every good one.

Comment: Especially bearing in mind that such users are often children.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have not seen any indication of that being the case, more of the opposite. The kind of trust in the need to voice one's unverified opinion that I refer to usually comes with age.

Comment: Ah. The one I was thinking of was 14 when he was posting (2015/16).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I get what you mean, its just that I have no specific examples and all the recent-ish young posters have been pretty transparent and more interested in asking than answering. I have seen what you refer to in other communities though, and may have myself been *that annoying guy* in my younger years.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 6):

I know its not at all related to how good a moderator you would be but I am interested in the following:

**What is your experience, either professionally or otherwise, in the Aviation industry?**

Comment: I find it amazing that someone dislikes this question enough to downvote.

Comment: @AEhere Its fine thats what this is for. It is completely tangential to being a moderator. It's more out of interest - "why are you here" sort of question. I'm interested in general how many enthusiasts we have vs professionals in our community. Kind of wish there was a poll feature!

Comment: Tangential does imply a point of contact. Being a moderator requires a degree of trust from the community at large, and sharing your background in our common field of interest is a good way of building it.

Answer (score 6):

Being a moderator means sometimes that for the good of the community you might have to do things with which you disagree. How would you deal with such scenarios?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @DeltaLima there are users I would have preferred not to suspend. Or I disagree with certain results on Meta, but I still abide by that final result.

Answer (score 6):

The site is growing. As ymb1 recently noted, we get twice as many questions per day as five years ago. Are there any long-standing policies you'd like to look at to see if they've outlived their usefulness?

Answer (score 5):

Why is this site (or SE as a whole) important to you? (Preferably in as few lines as possible.)

Answer (score 3):

What do you think the site needs more of in terms of moderating?

Answer (score 2):

On this site or another SE site, what moderator action(s) you witness that you appreciate the most, and why?